# Regex with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have an sql statement:

```
uPdate emp set emp_note='I am set to this ' where emp_name='John';
```

I want to substitute oracle specific statements in upper case so I do the following:

```
   +89      $line =~ s/ where / WHERE /ig;
   +90      $line =~ s/ set / SET /g;
   +91      $line =~ s/^select/SELECT/ig;
   +92      $line =~ s/^update/UPDATE/ig;
   +93      $line =~ s/^delete/DELETE/ig;
   +94      $line =~ s/^insert/INSERT/ig;
   +95      $line =~ s/ and / AND /g;
   +96      $line =~ s/ from / FROM /g;
   +97      $line =~ s/ in / IN /g;
```

The above also replaces the text which are values (I am set to this). For example above will render the statement as:

```
UPDATE emp SET emp_note='I am SET to this ' WHERE emp_name='John';
```

How can I avoid this to set perl to substitute only keywords and not the values inside the SQL statement?

The problem also is that I cannot use any SQL packages available with perl so I have to go with plain old regex way.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "Stop playing around with regex and learn to love [`SQL::Translator`](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL::Translator)".

Comment: I do not have access to these packages. Is there an alternative?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828

Comment: Of course I know to install CPAN but unfortunately you can do very little on a Unix box which does not have C compilers installed.

Comment: So basically you need to replace some set of strings with another, but only if not delimited by single quotation marks?

Comment: @Somenath — You can (a) Install C compilers and (b) Build on another box and then copy the files over.

Comment: @Quentin - I am not the admin. I cannot do that inside a company :)

Comment: @raina77ow - Yes that should be it.

Comment: @Somenath — So go to the admin and tell them what you need in order to do you job efficiently.

Comment: If I could do that with success then I already would have done that. I already tried it earlier but of no use.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to be very difficult to write a regular expression which can comprehend SQL syntax and only substitute the things you want. Actually, it's probably impossible because regexes themselves can't parse a grammar like SQL's. You might be able to wrangle it so that it won't substitute things inside quotes, but that wouldn't be pretty and it also wouldn't be a complete solution anyway.

So what you need is something that can actually parse SQL and then reassemble the parsed statements with your keywords in uppercase as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Using capture groups, you can easily choose which part of the match you want to uppercase:

```
use strict;
my $query = "uPdate emp set emp_note='I am\' set to this ' where emp_name='John'"; 
$query =~ s/('[^'\\]*(?s:\\.[^'\\]*)*')|\b(update|where|set|select|delete|insert|and|from|in)\b/$1\U$2/gi;
print $query;
```

The first branch describes what you want to avoid, the second branch is the target.

Answer (score -1):

use host variables instead of literal strings in your sql statements.

you should use them anyway for security considerations (danger of sql injection).

every decent api supports them. if yours doesn't, the 'security' token will almost surely make your admin install another one which does ... ;-)